# Problems with Cyrillic. Using AJAX, PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, cyrillic

I have a database with such parameters:

```
character_set_client: utf8
character_set_connection: utf8
character_set_database: utf8
character_set_filesystem: binary
character_set_results:utf8
character_set_server: cp1251
character_set_system: utf8
```

I am not using JQuery. I put data into DB with an AJAX. Everything works fine until I want to get cyrillic data from database. What I see in a browser is � instead of cyrillic symbol. Can you please show me a place with a problem? Thanks.

Comment: The problem is probably with your php code. How do you connect to the database?

Comment: I added these:
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=cp1251');
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'cp1251'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'cp1251'");
... and everything work now.

Comment: Glad to know that, but I suggest you to convert the database and your code to utf8 eventually. 1 byte national encodings are outdated now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to give you an advice. Check everything step by step and don't forget to make a backup before you do anything.

1) Change your character_set_server: cp1251 to utf8. You may do it in your mysql configuration file my.cnf. When you change it - you have to restart mysql. Add the following:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

2) Look at your database. Does information look fine inside it? If not - check how do you save your data.

3) Check your meta. It should be looking like that:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Your title</title>
</head>
```

4) You can provide you encoding type via php headers:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

This code should appear before any output in your script.

5) Check you browser. Sometimes I forget to change encoding from manual to automatic. Or you may change it manualy to UTF-8.

Hope, it will help you.